# Intuition for How Polar Graph Transformations Work

Tags: linear-transformations, polar-coordinates, rotations, transformation, reflection

I am learning about polar graphs for the first time, and I ran into some trouble understanding the transformations of polar graphs.

From https://brilliant.org/wiki/polar-curves/, the following linear transformations can be performed on a polar curve:

> Rotations about the pole can be performed in polar form by replacing the parameter $θ$ with $(θ−ϕ)$; this will rotate the curve counterclockwise by $ϕ$ radians.

> A reflection about a line $θ=ϕ$ can be performed by replacing the parameter $θ$ with $(2ϕ−θ)$.

> A reflection about the pole can be performed by replacing the parameter θ with $(θ−π)$.

Where did each of these replacement parameters come from (especially that of a reflection about a line)/why do they work to transform the polar graphs in that way? Another point of confusion I have is that a rotation about the pole seems to have the same form as a reflection about the pole, with the only difference being that the latter specifies $ϕ=π$. How is the form for reflection and rotation around the pole the same, yet it produces different results?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> The polar angle is conceptually a Cartesian coordinate, but measures angle counterclockwise about the pole. Adding a constant ($\theta\mapsto\theta'=\theta-\phi$) "shifts" the angle by $\phi$. Since $\theta=\phi$ when $\theta'=0$, the "new" angle $\theta'$ is rotated relative to the old. <> "Reflection about the pole" is a half-turn rotation, so maybe the name is not ideal. <> For reflection, $\theta\mapsto\theta'=2\phi-\theta$, the geometric intuition is that $\theta'$ increases _clockwise_ (the plane is "flipped over"), and the line $\theta'=\phi$ is fixed.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you so much! As a new learner of the polar coordinate system, I really appreciate your clear and concise explanation, which has clarified my doubts.